# How to Submit Google Form data without confirmation page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to remove the confirmation page, that is shown after clicking submit.

Instead when I click submit, the form should just refresh showing emptied data fields again , & display a  message saying" your data is submitted " with the data reflecting in the spreadsheet. & So, I can fill in data again without pressing back.

I have little knowledge of Html so this is getting tricky for me, but I figured from the source code I'll need to change this line of code -

```
link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" 

href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/URL LINK----/oembed?

url=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/URL  LINK-----/viewform&format=xml"
```

please correct me if I am wrong, What code should I input to make the desired change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the form, to change where you get sent after completing the survey. 
To my knowledge, it is not necessary to change the code.

Comment: Yea true, But I don't think you can remove the confirmation page on the form.  That's what I want to do. remove any confirmation page all together

Comment: No, you can, I just don't remember how.

Comment: Or at least you can make it re-direct, instead of going to the confirmation page.

Comment: yes, true, re-direct would work for me. But I don't know the code for redirect. would you be able to help?